# SCCM WMI Get Patches that require reboot

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, powershell, wmi, sccm-2012

How can i get all patches that require a reboot before running the install process using WMI and SCCM. So far i have this wmi query that lists all the available patches but none of the properties returned indicate anything about patches being required or not.

```
function Get-CMMissingUpdate {
param (
$computer = "localhost"
)
    Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareUpdate" -Namespace "ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK" -ComputerName $computer
}
```

Has anyone used anything else to find this information from SCCM 2012 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to filter on the `EvaluationState` property of the updates that are returned. There are several types of Evaluation States for pending reboots, they are listed on the [technet page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155451.aspx) for the sccm client sdk. States 8,9, & 10 are for pending reboots. Looking at your function, I would do something like

```
function Get-CMMissingUpdate {
param (
$computer = "localhost"
)
    Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareUpdate WHERE EVALUATIONSTATE = 8 OR EVALUATIONSTATE = 9 OR EVALUATIONSTATE = 10" -Namespace "ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK" -ComputerName $computer
}
```

If you're going to feed raw syntax instead of using powershell, whatever floats your boat. I don't have any pending sccm updates right now, or time to rig up a test box, but this should get you going.

Comment: The evaluation state will change to those states you have mentioned only after an `installUpdates` has been issued. I am looking to find out which updates require a reboot before installing them.

Comment: You can't know that, because the only language MS gives in their bulletins is that an update *may be required*. This is because it's impossible to know what files will be in use when the updates are being installed.

Comment: Okay thanks, i was able to use your evaluation state to get me what i needed.